# Is it OK to place more classes in one .h file, or more structs in one .h file?

Tags: c++

Is it OK to place more classes in one .h file, or more structs in one .h file?

I have two simple structs, and right now I have separate .h and .cpp files for both.
Initially they were classes and not structs, but because everything is public
I decided to make them public.

Please give me some suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is, there is nothing wrong (that forbids you to do so) in doing that.

Comment: Suggestion: if it works, don't fix it.

Comment: As your project grows, it might be an advantage to be able to find a `struct`'s declaration by finding the file with the same name.

Comment: @Magnus otoh I sometimes value the fact that structs that semantically belong together are in the same file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong. An header file may contain more than 1 classes..! Go ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

If the structs/classes are related to one another then stick them in the same file - makes sense.

Think of it like packages in java.

Comment: No, please don't think of header files like packages in Java. They're completely different.

Answer (score 0):

yes we can have multiple classes as well as multiple structures in a h file.